# asymptotic distribution for MLE - Borel distribution

Tags: asymptotics, maximum-likelihood

Suppose we have sample $y_1,y_2,...y_n$ from a borel distribution

$$P(Y=y;\alpha)= \dfrac{1}{y!}(\alpha y)^{y-1}e^{-\alpha y} , y=1,2..$$

The MLE of $\alpha$ is $\hat{\alpha} = 1-\dfrac{1}{\bar{y}} $

By using that $\Big(\bar{y}  - \dfrac{1}{1-\alpha} \Big) \rightarrow N \Big(0,\dfrac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)^3} \Big)$

How can I find the asymptotic distribution for $\hat{\alpha}$ (MLE)

Answer (score 1):

This is a Property of MLE.
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}-\alpha)\xrightarrow{d}N(0,I^{-1})
\end{equation}

So,you just need to calculate the inverse of fisher information matrix $I^{-1}$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Consistency More details could refer this link.